# Attribute Error occurs when performing division in PyCharm 5.0.2

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on a Windows 64-bit machine and using Python 3.4 and PyCharm 5.0.2. I find that PyCharm gives me error even when I'm doing tasks as simple as divisions:

```
up = 22.33695
down = 1.2598
this = up/down
```

It gives me this error message:

```
Error evaluating: thread_id: pid7636_seq2
frame_id: 54197704
scope: FRAME
attrs: this
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd_vars.py", line 238, in resolveCompoundVariable
return resolver.getDictionary(var)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getDictionary'
```

I really can't understand where I did wrong or if this is a bug in PyCharm. Can you help?

Comment: Is that your full code? I have the same setup as you and it runs perfectly on mine.

Comment: @Remuze It IS the full code. I'm starting to wonder if there were any problems when I installed my PyCharm.

Comment: That's certainly unusual. In PyCharm the debugger (pydevd) manages the execution of your code. I can't even find the resolver.getDictionary(var) reference in current pydevd code. You could try putting an import pdb;pdb.set_trace() in that module and stepping through, to see why the resolver is None. Or, upgrade to PyCharm 5.1.